# How can i use preg_replace pattern for this situation?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Can you help me for perg_replace pattern for my problem?
I want to make text bold and italic from preg_replace that words for text bold surrounded with `**bold**` and text italic surrounded with `##italic##`.

Example

```
$before = "Focus on the **user** and all else will ##follow##.";
$after = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $before);
```

And i want results like this, Should its patterns and replace pattern be? Thanks for everyone.

```
$after = "Focus on the <b>user</b> and all else will <em>follow</em>.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should suffice:

```
function format_text($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/(\*\*(.*?)\*\*)/', '<b>\\2</b>', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/(##(.*?)##)/', '<em>\\2</em>', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

It is important to note the question mark in `(.*?)` as we do not want a so-called *greedy match*. `.*` will try to match as much text as possible, but we want to limit our match to the "smallest" possible text within ** or ##.

Comment: thanks @ljacqu it works, and i have another problem too, can you help me with that?

Comment: @user3695637 Sure, but kindly set this question as resolved if this is the case.

Comment: You could also just do 1 preg_replace and replace the "pattern" and "replace" parameters with arrays, correct?